# Overlapping legend d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am creating the legends with triangle shapes. One is "Yes", the other one is "No". By running the code below, it generate two triangles but they are overlapping. I am trying to seperate them by using this line of code `.attr("y", function(d,i) {return 50+i*40;})` but seems like it doesn't work.
Can anyone tell me how to fix it? Thanks!
[Click here! This is an html sreenshot for this part of script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhcOb.jpg)

```
  var legendname = ["Yes","No"];   
     var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
              .data(legendname)
              .enter().append("g")
              .attr("class", "legend")
               .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
            return "translate(" + (w + 150) + "," + (m.t - 30) + ")";
          });

          legend.append("path")
              .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type("triangle-up").size(128))
             ***  .attr("y", function(d,i) {return 50+i*40;})
               .style('fill', function(d) {return color(d);});

             legend.append("text")
               .attr("y", function(d,i) {return 50+i*20;})
               .attr("x", 30)
               .text(function(d) { return d; })
```

Comment: Do the triangles or the text overlap? And what do you mean when you say that it "seems like it doesn't work"?

Comment: Just triangles. Text doesn't overlap. I mean I try to make them separate by this  .attr("y", function(d,i) {return 50+i*40;}), the line with stars. But nothing change, they are still overlapping.

Comment: it seems that your path is same, that's why triangles are overlapping

Comment: The path should be the same. Because they are the same triangles just different color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to update the translate y attribute of groups instead of the paths. And also there is no need for extra calculations for y attributes of texts and paths then.

```
.attr("transform", function(d, i) {
        return "translate(" + (w + 150) + "," + (30+i*40) + ")";
 });
```

**Working Code Snippet:**

```js
var w=40; //Sample chart width
 var color = d3.scale.category20c();
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr({ height: 500, width: 400 });

var legendname = ["Yes", "No"];
var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
  .data(legendname)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend")
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    return "translate(" + (w + 150) + "," + (30+i*40) + ")";
  });

legend.append("path")
  .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type("triangle-up").size(128))
  .style('fill', function(d,i) {
    return color(i);
  });

legend.append("text")
   .attr("dx",10)
   .attr("dy",".4em")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d;
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```